# How to set the values in Textview of MainActivity from simple class

Tags: android

I have two classes One is MainActivity.java and other is simple Java class ConnectMe.java.  I have Single Button and Single EditText on MainActivity. I am using a button to Login So it is named also as btnLogin. On its clickListener, I am taking the Ip from the EditText(in string format) and  calling the Login function from the ConnectMe.java class which takes string as a parameter.

Now in ConnectMe class I check if the application is connected to the server it should show the Connected Message in EditText and Also it should show the Toast on MainActivity. And I have no Idea How to do this as I am new to android.

here is my sample code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button btngLogin;
    EditText etIp;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                ConnectMe connectMe = new ConnectMe();
                connectme.LogMeIn(etIp.getText().toString);
            }
        });



    }
```

here is my java class for connection

```
public class ConnectMe {

     MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();


    void LogMeIn(String ip){

   MyConnectedmethod.Connectednew (new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

         mainActivity.setText("connected");  

}    
}
```

I know the code is not proper, But I just want to give you an idea. I am getting the null point exception on the line in which I am setting text of EditText.

With some research, I have find out that I can not touch the views from the Thread and Runnable directly . and I was told to use runOnUiThread. like mainActivity.runOnUiThread but it is also not helping giving error of nullpointexception.

So Please help me as I am new to android programming

Answer (score 2):

A lot going on here.

1. There's basically no instance in which you should instantiate an activity.
2. The Activity doesn't have a .setText() method. So that's the null pointer.
3. There's a much easier way to do a simple worker task than creating your own thread and managing it yourself. Use AsyncTask
   http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

EDIT:
You can run as many AsncTasks as you like. Without more context, it's hard to say exactly what your best approach is. But, it sounds like you probably want to run some kind of service. (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html). There's a couple different flavors available, depending on what you want to do. If it needs to run all the time, rather your app is running or not, then use a start service. If it needs to run only so long as the UI is going, then a bound service is the option. If it needs to do something every so often than some combination of intent service/broadcast receiver/alarm manager is the route.

You may not even need a service. If you're just loading several things use the loader manager. For downloading content a SyncAdapter may be the way to go. The point is that after 24APIs most common tasks already have a ready made solution. So, in most cases, you don't need to fiddle with threads yourself.

Comment: Well Thanks a lot for replying me . But in fact you cleared me many things. I also wanted to use async task but the problem is I have many functions which should be run like a thread or asynchronously  . So please clear me , that in the same class in my case ConnectMe , can I use multiple async ?

Answer (score 0):

The NullPointerException happens because you`re missing to declare what object Button btngLogin refers to.

```
btngLogin = findViewById(R.id.yourbuttonnameinxml);
```

Do the same with your EditText.

Answer (score 0):

i think you better read this first, starting another activity with intents and sharing a message between two activities (classes): http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html